# Copy and Transpose data from one sheet to another with rows offset each time

Tags: range, copy-paste, transpose

Im trying to copy a range of data from one sheet and then transpose this onto another sheet when a button is pressed to start macro "Update". I don't want to overwrite the previous data so each time the button is pressed, I want the data to be pasted below.

My code worked for the first set of data but I cannot figure out how to have the variable 'row' go up each time and input it correctly into the range function for where to put the pasted data.

I'm aware this is quite basic, however, I haven't had to code for a while and cannot find my answer online.

Here is my exact code:

```
Dim Row As Integer
Row = 3

Sub Update()

Dim Col As Integer

Worksheets("Supplier Database").Range("X3:AE27").Copy
Worksheets("Baseline Ranking").Range("B,Row").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Row = Row + 8

End Sub
```